# Need an overview of non-enterprise databases for .NET

Tags: sql, database

For smaller websites which are view-only or require light online-editing, SQL Server 2008, Oracle, and MySQL are overkill.

In the PHP world, I used SQLite quite a bit which is a e.g. 100K file holding hundreds of records which you speak to with standard SQL.

In the .NET world, what options do we have, I've seen:

- SQL Server 2008 Express (free but the files are bloated 2-10MB with just a couple records)
- SQL Server Compact 3.5 (seems interesting)
- Vista.db (not free?)
- What about SQLite with .NET, have any of you had success with that?
- Any other small, no-nonsense, SQL databases for .NET there?

I would particularly be interested in something like SQLite but that supports CLR type system and LINQ.

Comment: Not sure why you're discounting MySQL, its not exactly heavyweight.

Comment: Because if you have 20 websites (e.g. in a teaching scenario where each student has their own database-backed website) and you want to zip them, take them somewhere else and set them up on another server, you just do it with SQLite since it is just a file. MySQL is disconnected etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe [this Wikipedia RDBMS comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems) might help you in making your choice.

- SQLite [works just fine](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) with .NET.
- I second Edoode's suggestion of Firebird - that works great for me.
- [Be very careful](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/c39ae613-7513-4608-9572-9afa556e1699/) when using SQL Server CE in multi-threaded applications.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use Interbase at work, so I came to [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org).
First I had to use it, now I love it.

There's a [.NET Data Provider](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=netprovider) (ADO, DDEX).

U can even use it without setting up a server, like you do with SQLite (direct access to the database file).

It's actively developed and "open source".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any database that supports the CLR type system, even SQL server uses their own types.

Besides the already mentioned alternatives there is also [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [db4o](http://www.db4o.com) which is not SQL but a fully managed object store for java and .NET.